# What is the difference between перенести and перевести?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, дієслова, non-native-speaker, verb-prefixes

I am more specifically asking about when they mean 'to transfer something', not the other meanings like with перенести meaning to undergo and to postpone. I thought that generally вести was usually used with people and that нести would be used with objects, вести mening to lead and нести to mean carrry. So I imagined перевести would be used for when transffering people, and перенести for transffering inanimate objects. But that doesn't seem to be the reality, like in these examples:

> Гриценко перевів у надлишкове майно 919 танків - у три рази більше, ніж зараз є у ЗСУ - Вінник

Here I would be expecting to see переніс, since they are transffering tanks.

> Як перенести всі дані з одного смартфона на інший

This one follows my reasoning

> Як перевести гроші з Польщі в Україну

> Як перевести бізнес в онлайн?

> Як перевести оплати в телефон і почати користуватися онлайн-банкінгом – поради експерта

Again why not перенести.

Is it simply because you use some words with one and others with the other, or is there some logic I am too ignorant to notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Very superficial answer, I haven't looked deeply, please feel free to correct me.)

Перенести derives from нести — to carry. The primary meaning is that you *physically carry something* from one place to another. But it can also be used (idiomatically?) at least in the following cases:

- carry (transfer) *data/information* from one location to another (e.g. “я переніс дані зі старого комп'ютера на новий” — I moved data from old PC to new PC).

Перевести derives from вести — to lead. The primary meaning is that *somebody follows you* and in that way you make them to change their location. But it can also be used (idiomatically?) at least in the following cases:

- make something to change its *state*, turn something to other *mode*, ascribe somebody to other *category* (e.g. “перевести війська в режим бойової готовності” — to put army into combat readiness).

So:

> Гриценко перевів у надлишкове майно 919 танків…

It's not about moving tanks, it's about *reclassifying* as a “excessive property”.

> Як перевести гроші з Польщі в Україну.

For wire transfers:

- перенести гроші (the worst idea):

  - You could say “як перенести гроші через польсько-український кордон” (how to carry money across the Polish-Ukrainian border) — but that would mean literally carrying bags of cash (not a wire transfer) on your feet (not even using any transport; (пере)нести in its original meaning relates only to carrying by feet; for carrying via any transport use (пере)везти).
  - You may probably try extending data/information transferring semantics to virtual money in some cases (something like “я переніс усі свої заощадження в надійніший банк” — I moved all my savings to more reliable bank), but it's a quite limited set of cases (particularly, it must be obvious from the context that we are talking about non-cash money, because otherwise the physically-carrying-cash-by-feet connotation will prevail). In the discussed quote it would sound just weird.
- перевести гроші (probably not the best but sometimes used way):

  The state-changing/mode-turning/category-ascribing semantics can probably be extended to virtual money — i.e. like “a wire transfer is *ascribing the money to another account*”. Перевести гроші is [sometimes used](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma%3D%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%7C%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22%5D+%5Blemma%3D%22%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%96%22%5D) and even is [mentioned in some old dictionaries](http://sum.in.ua/s/perevodyty); however modern style guides often discourage its usage ([1](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/perevodutu-j-perekazuvatu), [2](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/uk/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/), [3](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/uk/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/)). (Maybe перевести гроші can be considered as an *obsolete* way to say about money transfers that is still alive only due to Russian influence, but I can't say that for sure, maybe it's still perfectly correct but just not so often used.)
- переказати гроші:

  Казати means to say, to tell, and переказати means to retell, so it's not fully clear for me how the meaning of переказати гроші arouse. Never-the-less переказати гроші is the most popular way to say about wire transfers nowadays.

> Як перевести бізнес в онлайн?

That's about *transforming* your business (so, again, category/mode/state changing).

> Як перевести оплати в телефон і почати користуватися онлайн-банкінгом…

Probably somewhat poorly-worded way to say that you *change the way you make your payments*, i.e. *transform* your payment-related habits.

Comment: Дякую за ясне пояснення) серйозно допомогло мене. До речі ці сайти чудові, буду їх користуватися в майбутньому

Comment: isn't it also possible to distinguish "bring (to)" and "fetch (from)" with this verb pair somehow? as a native speaker of a language which clearly separates those two, this always bugged me in Ukrainian; I've probably used it wrong all the time...